# How to Create a shortcut to files / folders on a drive with different / changing letters (root)?

Tags: shortcuts

I have seen this question asked and answered many times but the location one usually desires to create the shortcut is on the actual drive with the different letters.

I would like to create the shortcut on the drive with the permanent letter.

So, let me explain further.

I have a C Drive and a G Drive.  The C Drive is always C and it's on a **Windows XP** computer. The G drive may be G today, but H tomorrow.

How can I create a permanently working shortcut on the C Drive that points to the G, sometimes H, external hard drive?

P.S. I am referring to an external hard drive, but I would also (not instead) be interested in the answer if it were a usb flash drive. (Keep in mind the shortcut is being created on the drive with the permanent letter).

Thanks.

Comment: Is this specific to windows? Only XP? Can you add links to the previous entries where this question was asked/answered?

Comment: Yes, it is most likely specific to Windows. To XP, no. Any Google search will easily show this being answered with regards to creating a shortcut on a flash drive to access a file or folder on the usb flash drive.

Comment: You’re hardly the first person to ask this question; see [here](http://superuser.com/questions/98924/how-do-I-make-an-external-hard-drive-keep-the-same-drive-letter-permanently), [here](http://superuser.com/questions/421126/Windows-7-renames-my-external-hard-drive-to-a-different-letter), and [here](http://superuser.com/questions/540604/using-commands-in-a-shortcut-target).  Unfortunately, I didn’t see any great answers to those questions; but, if you look, you might find one that’s good enough.

Answer (score 0):

Besides trying to ensure that the drive letter doesn't change (or change it back if it does), one possible (but tedious) workaround could be to create batch files/scripts that search each drive for the file/folder and launch it if found.